# One VLC instance for different file types

Tags: windows, audio, vlc-media-player, mp3, wav

Is it possible to have two instances of VLC Media Player, one that plays WAV files exclusively and the other that plays MP3 files exclusively? I have to often listen to some WAV sound effects files to check that they sound good, but in between I like listening to music (MP3 files).

Basically, here's the scenario; I'm listening to music while I download a sound pack. I pause the song, listen to the sounds, then continue the song. In a single instance of VLC, this loses my progress on the song, i.e. when I play it again it starts from the beginning. I can of course use jump forward to where I was, but then I'd have to memorise my position every time.

What I'd like to be able to do is have one instance of VLC playing my music, then pause that, listen to the WAVs in *another* instance, then continue the song when I'm done.

I open files by simply clicking on them so I'd want VLC to automatically open them in a specific instance based on the extension. This is in Windows 8.1, by the way.

(I realise I can do this by, for example, using Windows Media Player for WAVs, but I prefer VLC for any audio playback.)

Comment: On Win, you can set VLC to use a separate instance for every 'launch', so first launch, set up playlist of mp3s, then double-clicking another file will open a new instance. [I'm not on my PC now so can't look up the details, sorry]

Comment: I did discover that, and I considered it as an option. However for the WAVs, there are usually packs of at least 30 separate files, and I'll be listening to about 10 that I select at random, just double-clicking them from within the ZIP. Each is like less than a second long as well. Having a brand new instance for every one would cause a lot of window closing, not very convenient.